# How to increase current output of an electromagnet controller?

Tags: power, current, pcb-design, circuit-design

I am modifying [a Grove electromagnet controller](https://www.seeedstudio.com/Grove-Electromagnet-p-1820.html) (schematic below) to output more current with the same inputs. The controller unmodified takes in a 5V power input and a signal of 0-5V with 0-20mA. The output is 0-5V with 0-400mA. So its basically a current amplifier. What I am trying to do is redesign the controller by changing or adding components for the controller to output the same voltage with 0-1A current.

I know the desired current can be reached by changing the components and making sure they have the right power rating but I don't know which components to change and what specific components to replace them with.

The product is open source so I can modify it as needed. I know the electromagnet itself that comes with the controller can't handle that current but I am using different electromagnets for my project. Also, I know adding a transistor and an external power source is more logical to get the needed current output but I am using 32 electromagnets for my project and it's not possible to have a power source for each coil.  [image: Schematic of controller]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing on there that limits the current, it's just acting as a switch. The only limiting factor in the output current will be the failure of the FET.

The [FET](https://statics3.seeedstudio.com/images/opl/datasheet/0440200P1.pdf) claims a maximum continuous drain current of 2.1A, so it should *already* be capable of switching a 1A electromagnet with no changes.

In the assembly as-sold, the factor that limits the current *is the electromagnet itself*.

Comment: if the coil is the only limiting factor, then if I increase the 5V input, the current will increase?

Comment: Correct, though the fet will fail at 20V, and the inductive kickback when the fet switches off may cause it to fail at a lower voltage.

Comment: i will try it with 12V and see what happens. Thanks!